# Intellij IDEA 2017.2 заменяет знаки в HTML

Tags: html

Подскажите где в настройках отключить подстановку знаков в IntellijIDEA.
Если ставлю точку и начинаю набирать слово то IDEA заменяет '<'и '>' прописными символами HTML
[image: вот так это выглядит при наборе]
[image: это уже после нажатия tab]

 

На нижних скринах, тот же файл в WebStorm отображается корректно
[image: WebStorm тот же файл отображает корректно]
[image: WebStorm тот же файл отображает корректно]

Answer (score 1):

решено удалением файла emmet.xml из папки options